# Play BIOS sounds (with PC speaker) in Java or Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, audio, bios

Is it possible to play basic BIOS sounds with Javascript or Java?
I need sounds that can be played on PC computers without Sound Card.
Every PC has built-in PC speaker that can be useful in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269657/how-to-make-a-noise-on-the-pc-speaker-with-java

Comment: @JamesScholes Sound Card is required for this sound. I need something like `Sticky Keys` sound (press 5 times `Shift` to listen it)

Comment: For what it's worth, in Linux, you can do `try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("/dev/console"))) { out.write(7); }` (but even that might require the "pcspkr" kernel module to be loaded).

Comment: I would believe that it would be impossible to control the system speaker in Javascript, however you could in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyx4j-native` [library](http://pyx4j.com/pyx4j-native/index.html) was helpful for me.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.pyx4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>pyx4j-native</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

It have class [Beep](http://pyx4j.com/pyx4j-native/apidocs/com/pyx4j/jni/Beep.html) method [beep(int,int)](http://pyx4j.com/pyx4j-native/apidocs/com/pyx4j/jni/Beep.html#beep%28int,%20int%29).

Play any sound is so easy with this library!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Java and exec an external program:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("beep.exe"); //not sure Beep.exe is a real thing
```

Which program to exec? Not sure, but look here for inspiration:

https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt

or write your own:

http://www.frank-buss.de/beep/

Note that using exec is inherently platform-specific and thus frowned upon in Java. However, what you are trying to do is platform specific, so this is your best option.

Other things worth trying/thinking about:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

But I think that beeps on the soundcard.

And

```
System.out.print( (char)7 );
```

but I'm not sure that will always work.